# Core Data Failing on saveToURL on UIManagedDocument

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, uimanageddocument

I'm trying to set up core data but when i'm running `saveToURL` on the `UIManagedDocument` it's failing to create it. This is my code;

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIManagedDocument *currentUserDatabase;

@synthesize currentUserDatabase = _currentUserDatabase;

- (void)setCurrentUserDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)currentUserDatabase
{
    _currentUserDatabase = currentUserDatabase;
    [self useDocument];
} 


- (void)isUserLoggedIn
{
    if (!self.currentUserDatabase) {
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Current User Database"];
        self.currentUserDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    }
}

- (void)useDocument
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.currentUserDatabase.fileURL path]]) {
        [self.currentUserDatabase saveToURL:self.currentUserDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"create success");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"create failed");
            }
            //[self getCurrentUser];
        }];
    } else if (self.currentUserDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [self.currentUserDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            //[self getCurrentUser];
        }];
    } else if (self.currentUserDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        //[self getCurrentUser];
    }
}
```

`isUserLoggedIn` gets called first, but when it gets created, I get the log "create failed" - I don't understand because there is no errors. Are there any ways to get error messages? Anyone know why it's not working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pain is relieved, I really have to start reading my code letter for letter! I was using the `NSDocumentationDirectory` instead of the `NSDocumentDirectory`

Comment: Wow, I did the same!! I watched Paul Hegarty too, wow! Good to know I'm not alone. This later resulted in no persistent store error.